# localStorage Size Limits... What are the options?

Tags: javascript, dojo, mootools, local-storage

I plan to use persistant localStorage in one of my projects and i have found out that the size limitation is 5 MB (chrome). I searched other frameworks which implmented the same thing, like Mootools, Dojo, Lawnchair but i couldnt find out what are their size limitations.

Does anyone know what are the size limitation is in these. And what other options are there which i can use if not the one already stated above.

Comment: Fun fact: contrary to what you’d expect, the 5 MB limit is closer to 2600 characters than to 5000 characters due to the way the data is encoded internally ([UCS-2/UTF-16](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding)). Here’s a test: http://arty.name/localstorage.html

Comment: @MathiasBynens right, nice to know :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232872/is-5mb-the-de-facto-limit-for-w3c-web-storage

Comment: Surely that should be 2,600,000 characters? I doubt they used an encoding where each character takes 2KB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

localstorage limits are not tied to the javascript framework, but to the browser you're using. [Currently specs are suggesting to limit the storage space to 5MB](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space) and this is the space maximum available on modern browser

On older versions of internet explorer (IE<8) [userData behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which mimics the localstorage) has a limit of 128kb for page (512kb is the maximum amount for an intranet page)

anyway for a complete list see http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/

Comment: ex lawnchair http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/adapters/ is not using HTML5 localStorage, but various adapters are available, so i should still assume its maxed at 5 MB ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use IndexedDB, but [it's not supported by all browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb), but [it can be unlimited if user accept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692820/max-size-in-indexeddb/7867985#7867985).

Comment: the indexeddb is also not that reliable, some variant mobile browsers on android system, the limitation of around 50M does exist per test.

Answer (score 0):

If you store JSON into your localStorage you can save space using a compression tool, like : https://github.com/k-yak/JJLC