# How to increase local storage space to unlimited for a firefox add-ons?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, local-storage

I am creating a Firefox add-on to store data in the local-storage. But it is limited to 5MB. I want it to be unlimited. Is there any way to make the local-storage space unlimited ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can store on user harddrive instead. Using OS.File etc

Answer (score 2):

Like others said it is not possible to allocate unlimited space for local storage, each browser comes with it's own limitations.

Here's a suggestion, local Storage is GRATE for Key, Value pairs, so for any data that exceeds 5MB limit a better approach would be to use a database such as IndexedDB.

Comment: Using [`Sqlite.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Sqlite.jsm) is another option add-ons have. Or you can write your data to the disc yourself in any format using e.g. [`OS.File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm/OS.File_for_the_main_thread)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possoble (its a browser running on users machine not your own).. each browser gives a fixed space for local storage, that you will not be able to increase. also read these links

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9283791/3556874
2. http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space

Answer (score 1):

You can have an unlimited storage with WebSQL on Chrome extension only.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions

Answer (score 1):

A lot of time had past since this question was asked but since googling still points here, I'm adding suggestion to use `IndexedDB` as a client side storage instead of LocalStorage to bypass 5MB quota limit.

This is built in DB solution for browsers, with benefits of `fast data insertion` and `big storage capacity` (about `1GB` or `more` if needed, limit is only the hard drive)

[IndexedDB MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

[Official GitHub Example](https://github.com/mdn/to-do-notifications/blob/a33b62f2b03660ef949994c46d72140c7b8fcc77/scripts/todo.js#L344)

There is a lot of good recourses on using IdexedDB (YouTube, GitHub, Articles)