# browser extension and a (big?) database

Tags: javascript, database, browser-extension

I am thinking of building a browser extension that would need access to a database of around 30 thousand items, with no more than 3 attributes each. Having this embedded in a json object doesn't seem like the right thing to do, but databases is not something I know much about.

Having the database on a server is not an option.

What is the right path to take? Should I use a sql file and a library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the 30000 items are not changing, with 3 attributes each, assuming each attribute is 10 bytes (large enough for a long or a short string), your data is 900 kilobytes. Storing and loading a json object isn't terrible but you might want to look into [HTML5's local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747285/html5-localstorage-restrictions-and-limits) which can hold 5MB.