# how can i use local storage for storing values of multiple variables?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i use local storage for storing values of multiple variables ? is there any limit for local storage. which all browsers currently support local storage ?

Comment: standard sizes are 5 or 10 MB per domain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a good discussion regarding HTML5 Local storage limits
[HTML5 localStorage size limit for subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747285/html5-localstorage-restrictions-and-limits)

Regarding browsers, here is a list,

```
Firefox 3.5, Safari 4, IE8, Chrome 4+: HTML5 localStorage; these modern browsers all support the core localStorage functionality defined in the HTML5 draft.

Firefox 2.x and 3.0: Gecko globalStorage, a very early implementation similar to HTML5’s localStorage.

Safari 3.1 & 3.2: HTML5 Database Storage, because Safari 3.1 and 3.2 don’t support HTML5 localStorage.

IE6, IE7: userData persistence, a rarely used IE feature for associating string data with an element on a web page and persisting it between pageviews.

Google Chrome Pre 4: Gears Database API, which is built into earlier versions of Chrome and thus doesn’t require a separate install.
```

Here is alist of browsers that support this functionality.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194784/which-browsers-support-html5-offline-storage

There is no limit for the number of variables, a detailed explanation for using HTML5 local storage can be found [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)