# In a Session Storage key value pair, is there a character limit to the length of the value string?

Tags: javascript, compression, session-storage, pako

I have an object whose data exceeds 5MB.  I'm using pako to compress the data down to about 1.7MB.  I then try to store that compressed data into session storage.  For smaller objects this works fine, but for this larger object I exceed the quota.  Considering I'm calculating the data size to be below 5MB, I'm wondering if there is some other limit to what can be stored in session storage, such as string length of the value or the byte length of the Uint8Array.

```
cachedLookups = {
  ... //Tons of data
};
const stringifiedLookups = JSON.stringify(this.cachedLookups)
const compressedLookups = pako.deflate(stringifiedLookups);
sessionStorage.setItem(this.sessionStorageKey, compressedLookups);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.  This was answered previously by [Is there a limit to the key length for localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345979/is-there-a-limit-to-the-key-length-for-localstorage)

For SessionStorage with a single key value pair, there is no character limit, save that the combined data size of the key string and the value string do not exceed the ~5MB limit of the Storage.