# How is localStorage space allocated if a user has multiple browsers?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I believe the maximum storage is domain based...i.e. each domain gets x amount of data.

But what about when a user switches between browsers?

Do they use two completely separate spaces and similarly separate maximum data amounts.

Secondly,

is localStorage.a in Browser 1 different from localStorage.a in Browser 2?

**Similar SO**

[What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/max-size-of-localstorage-values)

[HTML5 localStorage size limit for subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747285/html5-localstorage-restrictions-and-limits)

**Reference**

[W3](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp)

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers vendors won't implement shared localStorage. Each browser that supports localStorage will have an independent instance of however it has been implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Put simply, yes they do. It is browser specific/domain specific storage.