# Sqlite,HTML 5 local storage or Android local data store APIs for storing long texts in mobile phones

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, mobile-application

I'm developing an android app using Cordova in which i have over 3000 long texts (each fits in about 5 pages in Microsoft Word). I want to know which storing system is the best for storing such huge data.

Sqlite,[HTML 5 local storage](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-html5mobile2/), or [Android local data store APIs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-androidstorage/), or something else maybe?

**EDIT**

Considering [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747285/html5-localstorage-size-limit-for-subdomains) HTML 5 local storage is out, due to its limitations. I'm looking for a storage system which at least be able to store 500 MB.

Comment: Try these :https://bitbucket.org/axemclion/indexeddb-cordova-ios/src

http://pouchdb.com/learn.html

Comment: @MohammedImranN `IndexedDB` is only available on iOS. I'm working on android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that using SQLite Database will be a good choice, but if you have a realy huge data, the best choice is to use MySQL or Oracle Database on a web server, and then develop REST APIs to communicate with the app. 
Here is a tutorial about [Using Android SQLite Database With Multiple Tables](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-sqlite-database-example/)

Comment: Can you use it offline without needing to use a web server? My app will be offline.

Comment: if your app will be Offline , so the Best approach will be the SQLite

Answer (score 1):

Factors to consider with respect to Local Storage.
**Local Storage size limit:**
Web storage provides far greater storage capacity (5 MB per origin in Google Chrome,Mozilla Firefox,and Opera; 10 MB per storage area in Internet Explorer;25MB per origin on BlackBerry 10 devices) compared to 4 kB (around 1000 times less space) available to cookies. ( source [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage))
**Local Storage Method.**
Web Storage:
Web SQL Database:
Indexed Database:
source: [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage), [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-browser-storage-past-present-future/)

All **MOBILE** broswers have varying degree of support for above local storage method.
The most widely supported method is **Web Storage**.
If you would like to store **more than the limits** mentioned above than you need to use the native (OS) features for storing data. Then **PhoneGap** is the obvious choice for accessing native features.

**Storage Options that exceed the above Local Storage Limits:**
**1) Sqlite Plugin:**
You can use the plugin maintained by brodysoft. link [here](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

**2) Native File access:**
Need to use cordova file plugins. link [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md)

Comment: +1 I will use sqlite as you mentioned in last part. Thank you.